# Getting error while setting the content-security-policy using Angular4

Tags: angular, content-security-policy

I am getting the following error while setting the `content-security-policy` using Angular4.

**Error:**

> Refused to connect to
>   'ws://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/812/lxo2oeas/websocket' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src
>   'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set,
>   so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
>
> Uncaught TypeError: event.data.indexOf is not a function at receiveMessage (out.js:4)

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
    content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval';
      style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
      script-src 'self' http://localhost:4200 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Myapp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I need to set the `content-security-policy` but getting those error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly indicate that `ws:` source expressions are allowed.

So either change your `meta` element to have this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
  content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval';
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
  script-src 'self' http://localhost:4200 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
  connect-src ws:">
```

…that is, add a `connect-src` directive with a `ws:` source expression.

Or else do this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
  content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' ws:;
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
  script-src 'self' http://localhost:4200 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

…that is, add the `ws:` source expression to your existing `default-src` directive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with **Angular 9.1.12** deployed in a **WildFly Server** (previously JBoss). At first I believed that problem was into `index.html` with `<meta>` tag (`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';'">`) but really the error was in the *WildFly* server specifically in the *response-header* setted in the `standalone.xml`.

`standalone.xml`:

```
            <filters>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="JBoss-EAP/7"/>
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
                **Here=>** <response-header name="Content-Security-Policy" header-name="Content-Security-Policy" header-value="default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"/>
                <response-header name="x-frame-options" header-name="X-Frame-Options" header-value="SAMEORIGIN"/>
                <response-header name="x-xss-protection" header-name="X-XSS-Protection" header-value="1; mode=block"/>
                <response-header name="x-content-type-options" header-name="X-Content-Type-Options" header-value="nosniff"/>
                <response-header name="strict-transport-security" header-name="Strict-Transport-Security" header-value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;"/>
                <response-header name="my-custom-header" header-name="my-custom-header" header-value="my-custom-value"/>
            </filters>
```

Then restart the **WildFly** server with the `jboss-cli` located into `bin` folder of *wildfly*:

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:reload
```